# The value of the property $ is null or undefined - local machine only

Tags: jquery

I realize that this error indicates that I am attempting to use the jQuery $ function before the jQuery library has been loaded. The mystery is that this solution ran correctly on my machine 2 weeks ago. Also, the current version **still runs correctly** on 2 of my coworkers machines. It just won't run on my machine!

What could cause something like this to happen on my local machine? I can't think of anything I could have done to cause something like this. My hosts file seems normal and I can't think of anything else to check. Any hints or clues are appreciated.

I don't think posting code will help in this situation so I'm keeping this short. Please let me know if more details are needed.

The way I am including jQuery is through the head of my html layout page (MVC):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've also tried:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Both seem to not work on my machine, but either one works on my coworkers machine.

Image of my browser console:

[image: Console]

Comment: How do you include jQuery?

Comment: Did you check your console?!... Are you running local server?

Comment: @RenePot - I add a reference in my html head: "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>"

Comment: @A.Wolff - I am running local host from visual studio. I checked the F12 developer tools and verified the jQuery is loaded before my script, if that's what you mean

Comment: @BrianLegg You have it as `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"`, right?

Comment: @A.Wolff That should be fine.

Comment: Show the way you are including jQuery by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: That should be perfectly fine. What does your console say?

Comment: @BrianLegg `local host from visual studio` I'm not a VS user but could be some VS config issue

Comment: I've updated my post to include the info

Comment: @BrianLegg One last thing, same issue using `jQuery` instead of `$`? And please answer it: any other error in console?

Comment: @BrianLegg Does your computer have Internet Connection? `:O` Try navigating to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js...

Comment: Adding console image to post and I tried using jQuery instead of $ as well, incase it was being overwritten, but no luck.

Comment: @BrianLegg Show your full code please!!!

Comment: Ah.. That crazy thing. Are you using IE? Try with a different browser?

Comment: The image of the console doesn't show the error you describe...?

Comment: Yes, I was using IE. It seems "most" of the functionality works when I change the target browser to FireFox. At least, the jQuery library loads :). Now I'm really curious what the issue was with IE. And yes, I'm online... I'm posting to SO on the same machine

Comment: LoL... Kill IE. @BrianLegg...

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I would in an instant if it weren't the companies standard browser. Grrrr....

Comment: Ha ha.. All the best.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I actually found the solution after much digging. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to my problem, and yes it was an IE issue only.

I had to go to Tools -> Compatibility View Settings and remove localhost from the list of websites. See image:

[image: View Settings]

After this change everything works perfectly. Thanks to all who helped guide me to the answer.

Comment: Yuck, Yuck, Yuck, Yuck!!! Die IE! `:P`